# Zsh dynamic expand to current git root

Tags: git, zsh

In Zsh, I can get the current Git root:

```
% echo $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

I would like to dynamically expand to this string somehow with a trigger.  That is to say, I want to expand some key string to the "current git repo root" seemlessly and continue to select files/directories from there.

For example if the trigger was "grt" and I type:

```
% copy grt
```

<kbd>tab</kbd>, "grt" is replaced with the current git repo root (if "grt" file/dir doesn't exist in the current directory).

It feels like I would have to hook into the completion system somehow.  Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to setup a function in your `.zshrc` like:

```
function grt()
{
    git rev-parse --show-toplevel
}
```

Then to use (two examples):

```
cd $(grt)
cp file1 $(grt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bindkey`:

```
bindkey -s grt '$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)\t'
```

The trailing `\t` character triggers expansion of the command substitution. If you omit it, `grt` simply expands to the `$(...)`, which you can then complete with <kbd>Tab</kbd> if you wish.

Comment: That is pretty cool.  But not being able to type "grt" in sequence could cause a good deal of confusion when I don't expect it.  :)

Comment: Ah, good point. I didn't play with it much, and I was assuming it had to be a single word, or that could escape it using `\grt` or something. I was wrong on both counts.